# How to achieve an overhanging image hero responsively

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate this image hero overhang, I have managed to do it using minus right on a positioned absolutely relative to a right-hand flex column but this doesn't work responsively for obvious reasons, any ideas on how to achieve this?

Picture of what i'm trying to create - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Saaq.jpg)

Here is a jsfiddle of my code - https://jsfiddle.net/EikHunter/6rbchaj7/7/

```
  <div class="pg-LandingHero">
    <div class="pg-LandingHero_Inner">
      <header class="pg-LandingHero_Header">
        <p class="pg-LandingHero_Kicker">This is kicker text</p>
        <h1 class="pg-LandingHero_Title">This is an image title</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="pg-LandingHero_Body">
        <div class="pg-LandingHero_Columns">
          <div class="pg-LandingHero_Column pg-LandingHero_Column-content">
            <p class="pg-LandingHero_Text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sed sapien quam. Sed dapibus est id enim facilisis, at posuere turpis adipiscing. Quisque sit amet dui dui.Duis rhoncus velit nec est condimentum feugiat. Donec aliquam augue nec gravida lobortis. Nunc arcu mi, pretium quis dolor id, iaculis euismod ligula. Donec tincidunt gravida lacus eget lacinia.</p>
            <a href="#" class="pg-LandingHero_Link">This is a link</a>
          </div>
          <div class="pg-LandingHero_Column pg-LandingHero_Column-image">
            <div class="pg-LandingHero_Item">
              <div class="pg-LandingHero_ImageContainer">
                <div class="pg-LandingHero_Image">
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I think if you go through the question I have achieved this - I have attached a picture of what I want to achieve, I have attached a fiddle to show you how I have achieved this now I am asking for input, it was a question posed to the community as I have achieved what I wanted but it isn't responsive. I would also like to see how other people achieve what I want to do.

Comment: What overhang are you talking about? From the image I would assume you are talking about the bottom part of the image that overlaps the white area below this section ... but then I don’t know why you are saying “using -right” would achieve that. Plus, if you are complaining that it wasn’t responsive, then you should also tell us what you want this to look like on small screens to begin with. Having the text and the image next to each other is probably not going to make much sense on a 320px mobile screen - so _what’s it gonna be then?_

Comment: Because the image overhangs on the right also, if you look at the jsfiddle there is a max width of 2900px on the container, It just needs to shrink and not overlap when brought down screen size, it doesn't matter what it looks like at 320px necessarily as it will just stack on top of each other, so how to do you create negative absolute object but keep it responsive without overlapping the viewport due to the - right

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, I think it should be fairly simple to get this layout by floating the image to the right, without any absolute positioning whatsoever. You could probably achieve the overhang on the bottom this way as well -- by putting the blue background on the text, its container will still stretch the whole width of the page, even though the line boxes are shortened to allow for the floated image.

I think this would help with your reponsiveness problem which, if I understand correctly, comes from the absolute positioning.

Comment: I have updated the image on the question for better understanding at the fact it overhangs right to the container also.